# Why is this integral operator NOT compact?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, compactness, compact-operators

Let $k \in C(\mathbb{R})$ be a function such that $k(t)>0$ for $|t|<c$, and $k(t)=0$ else. 
The operator $A: (C(\mathbb{R}),\|\cdot\|_{\infty}) \to (C(\mathbb{R}),\|\cdot\|_{\infty})$ given by
\begin{align*}
(A \varphi)(x) := \int_{\mathbb{R}} K(x,y) \varphi(y) dy \qquad x \in \mathbb{R}
\end{align*}
with $K(x,y):=k(x-y)$ is not compact? Why? (please prove this)

Comment: This is not a Hilbert-Schmidt operator.

Comment: As @RobertIsrael notes, the original title was inaccurate... I changed the title to reflect the actual question.

Comment: Don't deface your questions. People have put effort into posting an answer to your question. If you wanted it not to be online afterwards, you should not have asked it to begin with.

Answer (score 3):

Since $K(x,y)$ depends only on $x-y$, $A$ commutes with translation.
Moreover, if $\varphi$ is supported in an interval $[a,b]$, $A\varphi$ is supported in $[a-c,b+c]$.  Take a function $\varphi$ supported on $[0,c]$ and positive in $(0,c)$, so that $A \varphi \ne 0$, then 
$A$ is an isomorphism on the closed linear span of the functions
$t \mapsto \varphi(t + 3 n c)$, $n \in \mathbb Z$, which is infinite-dimensional.  In particular it can't be compact.